# I do not button to generate strings which are already stored in database

Tags: php, javascript, database, string, button

I have created something which is like a random string generator. What happens is that the user would click on a button and by using letters A and B it will construct a 3 letter string like these for example:

AAA
AAB
ABA
ABB
BAA
BAB
BBA
BBB

Now what I want is my randon string generation to link with the "SessionId" column which is in the "Session" Table of my database where these strings will be stored in. What I want is the button to generate a string which is already in the database. For example: strings AAA and AAB are already in the database so it should not generate these strings.

Does anyone know how to link this to my "Session Id" field in the "Session" Table?

My code is in jsfiddle so you can see how the button works and the code used, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tskNK/) to see

Comment: Don't use a three character string for a session id.  Use a guid instead.  It's sufficiently unrepeatable, and even though it can be "guessed" based on how it's calculated, it's *infinitely* harder to guess than a 3 character identifier.

Comment: you say it should and should NOT generate at the same time ... and if you generate strings for a user which you store in a session, you don't need a database. If you have a database, and get pre-generated strings from it, why then generate new ones? And if you generate new ones, you should test, if they are already in the database, then store them there and assign it to your user sesesion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's just a shot in the dark, but I'd guess you'd generate a string, check if it's in the DB, and, if so, generate a new one (& repeat).